# Pushing Object into Array then Looping Through Resulting Data Structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, parameter-passing

```
var cartTotal = [];
var priceValue = x;
var priceID = y;
```

After defining the above empty array, i have a loop which includes the following:

```
cartObj = {};
cartObj.priceID = priceValue;
cartTotal.push(cartObj);
total(priceID);
```

After looping through the above code a few times, will the resulting cartTotal array look like this:

```
cartTotal = [{priceID:priceValue},{priceID:priceValue}]       ?
```

The reason I ask is because I am trying to pass **priceID** to the total function below in order sum all of the priceValue numbers. Why in the total function, is **a.price** undefined? The cartTotal.length alert indicates that I have an Array with numerous values so the array is recognised within the function.

```
function total(price){
alert(cartTotal.length);
totalPrice = 0;
for(var i=0;i<cartTotal.length; i++){
a = cartTotal[i];
itemPrice = parseInt(a.price);
totalPrice += itemPrice;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `a.priceID`. That was the `key` you stored using.

No need for `a`, just use the array itself. Also, as it is a price, it is better to use float.

Code:

```
function total(price){
    alert(cartTotal.length);
    totalPrice = 0;
    var itemPrice;

    for(var i=0; i<cartTotal.length; i++){
        itemPrice = parseFloat(carTotal[i].priceID).toFixed(2);
        totalPrice += itemPrice;
    } 
}
```

Question: Why are you passing `price` as argument to the function?

Comment: priceID is passed to the total function when it is executed **total(priceID);**. So I thought when i define the function, i could have anything to represent this passed parameter. E.g.:

Comment: **function total(price){**  or **function total(a){** i have done a similar thing in the past. Why does price not represent priceID which is the passed parameter when the function is executed? thanks for you reply btw.

Comment: @bfavaretto Which `var s`?

Comment: On the OP code, `a`, `itemPrice` and `totalPrice`. On yours, `itemPrice` and `totalPrice` (I'd return the last one, instead of using a global).

Comment: currently the total function sits within another function where the priceID is declared. PriceID is not a global variable. Not sure whether I'll need to move total() elsewhere.. I dont have a very good understandng of how javascript should be constructed with regard to layout of functions etc.

Comment: Okay @Pete, my point was indeed to avoid global variables. Just make sure the variables are declared on a parent scope.

Comment: If i do move the total function and need to pass priceID, I thought I would have to use cartTotal.price as priceID would not be available... still not sure why using the price argument when defining itemPrice doesnt work? thanks for your help.